# How to add event to UICollectionView cells?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, target-action

I want to handle tapping UICollectionView cells. Tried to achieve this by using the following code:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cvCell";    
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];  

    // Some code to initialize the cell

    [cell addTarget:self action:@selector(showUserPopover:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    return cell;
}

- (void)showUserPopover:(id)sender
{
     //...
}
```

But the execution breaks at the line `[cell addTarget:...]` with the following error:

> -[UICollectionViewCell addTarget:action:forControlEvents:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9c75e40

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should implement the [UICollectionViewDelegate protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and you'll find the method :

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

that tells you when the user touch one cell

Comment: This only works if the touch event applies to the entire cell.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution I found is using UITapGestureRecognizer:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                               initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showUserPopover:)];
        [tapRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
        [tapRecognizer setDelegate:self];
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [cell addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```

But the didSelectItemAtIndexPath solution is much better.

Comment: helped me since I reused the cells in another scrollview.

Answer (score 3):

swift 4 of @sergey answer

```
override public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: conversationCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! Cell
    cell.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleCellSelected(sender:))))
    return cell
}

@objc func handleCellSelected(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){
   let cell = sender.view as! Cell
    let indexPath = collectionView?.indexPath(for: cell)
}
```